# How can I create a constraint that checks the uniquiness of the association of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In MySQL database I have a table called `Course` which have `classroom` and `timeslot` columns so I want to create a constraint that checks no two course can have the same association of `classroom` and `timeslot`. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique constraint with multiple columns like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Course ADD UNIQUE unique_classroom_time (classroom, timeslot);
```